# When to create new storyboard vs View Controller for a new screen?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

I am new to iOS development and cannot find an answer for this.

When should I create a new storyboard and when should I just create a new View Controller for a new screen?

`Launch Screen` and `Main` are two different storyboards. Let's say `Main` is login screen, so after user is logged in, he should see a new screen of something. Which method should I use to create that screen?

Comment: Why not just add a new scene to your storyboard?  That's the accepted way.  Then use segues to navigate between them, or a navigation controller.

Comment: @OwenHartnett alright, so when to create a new storyboard? And why LaunchScreen and Main are two different storyboards instead of one storyboard with two View Controllers?

Comment: Storyboards delineate a path the user takes through your application.  Most applications only need one storyboard.  There are circumstances where, based on a user's input, you need to take two wholly different paths, say one path if you're using an iPhone and another if it's on an iPad (but class sizes are supposed to handle this).  Another case is when a storyboard gets so big it makes sense to break it into smaller ones.

Comment: And for your second question, main is generally the app storyboard, and  LaunchScreen is only used for generating Launch screens (i.e. screens that appear at app launch time before execution is turned over to your app's code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To directly answer your last question, use the Main storyboard only for this:  Create the scene that your user will see when he is logged in.  Make that be the first view that is shown.  Then create another scene that is your login screen.  When your main screen is launched, have it check to see if you're logged in.  If not, it should modally launch your login screen.

Answer (score 4):

For most simple apps, a single Storyboard is all that's required to fit in your app UI. Yes, there is a Launch storyboard as well if you choose to follow modern best practices. So that's 2 total. And in many cases that's all you need.

However, "big" storyboards can get unwieldy in a few ways. For one, under the hood it's a giant XML file, so storyboards with tons of things of them can be slower to open on your Mac. Whether that bothers you or not is up to you. Also, sometimes Storyboards can be difficult to keep track of when merging if you're working on a team instead of solo. So, if you want to break up your app into multiple storyboards, you can, and iOS 9 has features to help make that easier than ever (storyboard references).

For my current app, I have 3 storyboards, each organized logically around functionality. One is for our multi-screen on boarding. Another is for the main app UI. The third is for our Settings screen, which has a deep hierarchy of navigable options. It made sense to break these off into separate Storyboards because they are quite distinct.

You might get confused because if you search around on Twitter or the Web you might see some developers they use one storyboard per view controller. Those people are nuts, don't listen to them. When you do that you're missing out on a number of great storyboard features, the biggest of course being segues.

Answer (score 2):

You will create new ViewController, new storyboard is required only when your layout design is different for different devices (i.e. iPad and iPhone) or if you cannot handle design for iPhone and iPad with same storyboard

Answer (score 1):

Since the login process sometimes involve multiple screens (Forgot pass, registration, etc..), what you can do is split the Login and Main to two storyboards.

Then, you make which to show from the app delegate:

```
if userLoggedIn() != nil  // No user logged in
 {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        if let rootVC : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController(){
            window?.rootViewController = rootVC
        }
} else{
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil)
        if let rootVC : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController(){
            window?.rootViewController = rootVC
        }
    }
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Set rootViewControllers on each storyboard and you are set.

This will also minimize the Main storyboard which in many cases can become huge with segues and VC's all over the place and makes it becomes less and less manageable.